# Split the str-11-str and take only middle values

Tags: c#, string, .net-core, split

I have a string as you can see below. What the easiest and best way to take the middle value only.

```
123456789-11-abcd
```

So, I just want to take the middle value which is in between two (-).I know we can split on - and then we can store the string array and then find the right string but that will lengthy. Is there any easies way.
TIA

Comment: use a regex: `".*-(\d)+-.*"`

Comment: `somestring.Split('-')[1]`

Comment: Thanks, I did the same as Michael  suggested but will try to regular expression one also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input_value = '123456789-11-abcd' # Consider this as a string 
Split input_value by '-' and it will generate an list say Split_list 
print second element from the Split_list 
output_value = Split_list[1] 
print(output_value) # Required Output